# Finding the Area of a Circle

Tags: python

I am new to Python and have a question about an assignment. I know how to write the code to find the area and circumference. However, I need to know how to do it using a *WHILE statement*. The result should print a table with the circumference and area for a radius of 1 through 5. I assume that I will need to use range() to accomplish the radius of 1 through 5.

Comment: show what you tried so far?

Comment: You say you know how to compute a circumference - you could share what you have and make clear how exactly you're having trouble using "while". This should provide some ideas https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while (hint: StackOverflow isn't here to write your code, it's here to help you solve problems with yours - the problem "I don't have any" doesn't count)

Comment: import math

def main():

    def calculateArea(radius):
        area = (math.pi * (radius ** 2))
        return area

    def calculatecircumference(radius):
        circumference = 2 * math.pi * radius
        return circumference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write something like this

```
radius = 1
while radius < 6:
    area = radius**2
    print(f'Radius={radius}   Area= {area}')
    radius += 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much.....that is definitely the assist I needed to fix my existing code.